# Twilio Caller ID From Workspace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I have a Taskrouter workspace set up that queues incoming calls and distributes them to workers.

When an incoming call gets to its final destination (i.e. the worker), it shows the incoming caller ID as our main number (i.e. the number that triggers the workflow) rather than the actual caller's number.

How do I change it so that the workers are seeing the actual caller's number?

I have it set up in accordance with this tutorial.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/dynamic-call-center/ruby/rails#0

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

That is the case with calls that are dequeued and sent on to the worker. You can [set the callerID using the `from` property in the JSON with the dequeue instruction](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/handling-assignment-callbacks#dequeue-linked-call-tracking), but you can only set that to a verified number or Twilio number within your account. [The documentation for `from` actually says](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/handling-assignment-callbacks#dequeue-linked-call-tracking):

> The caller ID for the call to the worker. This needs to be a verified Twilio number. If you need this to be the original callee number, please [Contact Support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact). If the "from" is missing and the Task was created using Enqueue verb, then we will use the "To" number dialed by the caller as the "from" number when executing "dequeue" instruction.

So, my recommendation, if you need the number to be the original caller, is to [contact support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact).